# ElasticSearch search query with a highlighter per index

Tags: java, elasticsearch, highlight

When performing an ElasticSearch search operation from Java code, typically you create a SearchRequest with some indices as parameter, since the search is done across several indices.
Now I would like to be able to use a separate highlighter for each such index, e.g.:

```
    // Define the indices to search on
    String[] indices = {"index1", "index2", "index3"};

    // Build the search request
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(indices);

    // Build the search source
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("field", "search term"));

    // Build highlighters for each index
    HighlightBuilder highlightBuilder1 = new HighlightBuilder().field("field1");
    HighlightBuilder highlightBuilder2 = new HighlightBuilder().field("field2");
    HighlightBuilder highlightBuilder3 = new HighlightBuilder().field("field3");

    // Add highlighters to the search source for each index
    searchSourceBuilder.highlighter(highlightBuilder1);
    searchSourceBuilder.highlighter(highlightBuilder2);
    searchSourceBuilder.highlighter(highlightBuilder3);

    // Set the search source on the search request
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```

However, the call to ***searchSourceBuilder.highlighter*** simply overwrites a previous highlighter, so this won't work. Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to instantiate more than one HighlightBuilder. HighlightBuilder uses pattern builder, to apply more points just add "fields" in the same HighlightBuilder instance.

```
String[] indices = {"index1", "index2", "index3"};

// Build the search request
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(indices);

// Build the search source
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("field", "search term"));

// Build highlighters for each index
HighlightBuilder highlightBuilder = new HighlightBuilder().field("field1").field("field2").field("field3");

// Add highlighters to the search source for each index
searchSourceBuilder.highlighter(highlightBuilder);

// Set the search source on the search request
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```

Comment: You mean here that "field1" would be defined on "index1", "field2" on "index2" and so on ? So this is how you can to different indices, but this is not enough, because:


1. I might have fields with the same name on different indices

2. I want to keep different parameters of the highlighter for each index, e.g.
I want to set highlightBuilder.maxAnalyzedOffset(10000) for a certain index and maybe 25000 for another index
So the question is how to retain this full flexibility of the highlighter per index ?

Comment: ".... how you can link to different indices" I meant above

Comment: In this case you could try [Multi Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html). You can configure HighlightBuilder for each index.

Comment: indeed, it seems the only workaround is to have multiple searches, each search query with its index and its own highlighter; however, I expect performance issues with that approach, at least compared to one search which runs in parallel on many indices